# Rule of five for derived classes

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been trying to understand how "rule of five" should be written for a derived class. Only thing I found online was how it should be written for base class. So given following `class A` how should it be written for `class B`?

```
class A {
  int a;
  std::vector<int> k;
  int *z;

public:
  int getA() const {return a;}
  std::vector<int> getK() const {return k;}
  int* getZ() const {return z;};

  A(int a, std::vector<int> k, int* z) : a(a), k(k), z(z) {}
  A(const A& Other) : a(Other.getA()), k(Other.getK()), z(Other.getZ()) {}
  A(A&& Other) : a(Other.getA()), k(std::move(Other.getK())), z(std::move(Other.getZ())) {}
  A& operator=(const A& Other) {
    return *this = A(Other);
  }
  A& operator=(A&& Other) {
    a = Other.getA();
    k = std::move(Other.getK());
    z = std::move(Other.getZ());
    return *this;
  }
};

class B : public A {
  char* t;

public:
  char* getT() const {return t;}

  B(int a, std::vector<int> k, int* z, char* t) : A(a, k, z), t(t) {}
};
```

**EDIT#1**

Thank you all for your comments. Yes, I am aware that I've missed destructor. I've forget to copy it, but it's less important for me.
Let me maybe rephrase my main concern - **how should e.g. copy constructor of B look like?** Regular constructor contains `class A` constructor. Should copy constructor of B also have some `class A` copy constructor? How should it look? Will that be in initialization list?

Comment: It's called "the rule of 3/5/0". The point is not necessarily to have all 5, but to **either** have 3, 5, or 0. Often 0 is the smartest choice, use it for both of your classes.

Comment: It does not look like you applied the rule correctly. You have 4 of the 5 definitions, you missed the destructor. But in this case, you should have applied to rule of 0 as all of your definitions are equivalent to the default versions.

Comment: It works the same way for derived classes. If you have to *override* any of the 5 (3), then you should override all 5 (3).

Comment: Can we assume that `z` being a pointer is a make-work project for the purposes of this example?

Comment: There is no difference for child classes. You should still follow the rule for the class itself.

Comment: You move ctor and assignment operator don't move. They copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the derived class, you can reuse the base part of the copy and move constructors/assignment operators defined in the base class and only add what's added in the derived class.

Before I show that, I've made a few corrections to the base class since it doesn't actually *move* anything. I also recommend not implementing this using *getter* methods. Go straight for the resource you need.

```
#include <utility>

class A {
    int a;
    std::vector<int> k;
    int *z;

public:
    // getters removed - not needed for this example

    A(int a, std::vector<int> k, int* z) : a(a), k(std::move(k)), z(z) {}
    
    // rule of 5 start
    A(const A& Other) : a(Other.a), k(Other.k), z(Other.z) {
        // note that z can't be an owning pointer in this example
    }

    // actually move the content of the vector and exchange the pointer
    // in the moved from object with a nullptr
    A(A&& Other) : 
        a(Other.a), k(std::move(Other.k)), z(std::exchange(Other.z, nullptr))
    {}

    A& operator=(const A& Other) {
        if(this == &Other) return *this;  // don't do anything if self-assigning
        return *this = A(Other);          // this uses the move assignment operator
    }

    A& operator=(A&& Other) {
        if(this == &Other) return *this;
        a = Other.a;
        std::swap(k, Other.k); // swap content, let Other destroy it
        std::swap(z, Other.z); // not important since it's not an owning pointer
        return *this;
    }

    ~A() = default; // ... as z is not an owning pointer
    // rule of 5 end
};
```

Now to the answer-part - How to reuse what you already defined in `A`:

```
class B : public A {
    char* t;

public:

    B(int a, std::vector<int> k, int* z, char* t) : A(a, std::move(k), z), t(t) {
        // again, t can't be an owning pointer
    }

    // rule of 5 start
    B(const B& Other) : A(Other), t(Other.t) {} // copies the A part + t

    // similar
    B(B&& Other) : A(std::move(Other)), t(std::exchange(Other.t, nullptr)) {}

    B& operator=(const B& Other) {
        if(this == &Other) return *this;

        // use the base class operator by specifying it explicitly
        A::operator=(Other); // use the base class' copy assignment operator
        t = Other.t;         // just add t
        return *this;
    }

    // similar as in copy assignment
    B& operator=(B&& Other) {
        if(this == &Other) return *this;
        A::operator=(std::move(Other)); // use the base class' move assignment operator
        std::swap(t, Other.t);          // and just swap t
        return *this;
    }

    ~B() = default;
    // rule of 5 end
};
```